# Strictly positive linear combination of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a matrix S of size $m \times n$.

How to find a linar combination of the $n$ column vectors of the form:

$x = col(1) + \sum_{i=1}^{i=n}{\lambda_i col(i)}$ such that all entries of $x$ are strictly possitive

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it could be:

You can formulate this problem into finding an interior point of a polytope. x having strictly positive elements translates to the condition: Sλ+col(1)>0 or −Sλ−col(1)<0 (<,> is understood element-wise), which is describing the interior of the polytope P described by −Sλ−col(1)≤0. Now, there are many ways of finding an interior point of P. (Notice, there must not necessarily exist one). You could use an optimization solver like CVX to find a feasible point of the equations describing P for example.

Comment: What about the initial point of the optim, how to find a valide one?

Comment: you don't need that in CVX.

Comment: Another thing to mention is, that CVX can not handle strict inequalities, so instead of $A\lambda + col(1) >0$, just make it $A\lambda + col(1) \geq 10^{-k}$, where $k$ is sufficiently big.